# What's a word for avoiding a question with a generic (fake) answer?

Tags: single-word-requests, questions

Examples...

> Q: Why is the sky blue?
>   A: Because God made it that way.
>
> (A kid to their parent)
>   Q: Why do I have to clean my room?
>   A: Because I said so.

What is it called when someone answers a question this way? I've said "That's not an answer, that's a 'cop-out'" but that's not right.

Comment: You forgot to add the Bill Clinton example: "it depends on what your definition of is is".

Comment: Also sometimes referred to as *skirting the issue*

Comment: @BZink: You should wait a little longer to see if there is a better answer. I have fav'ed this question, too.

Comment: *Non-answer* is widely used as well.

Comment: If you want to focus the answers you might want to describe what you are after even further; the examples have similarities, but they also have differences. Try to put it into words or find more examples.

Comment: "That's a cop-out answer" sounds fine to me.

Comment: I think the point is that there should be a word that represents "an answer that cops out", because there are other ways to cop-out.

Comment: "No comment" comes to mind with common examples found in the headlines every day, but I would also like a greater sample set to be able to categorize these types of dialogue more specifically than that the reply begins with "because."

The agent in the answer makes a great difference.  "It is what it is," for example, is a pointless pit of semantic void, but "Because I said so," or even simply "because" implies a credibility argument.

Comment: [Kid](http://www.just-jokes.net): Mom can I go to "Friend's" house?
<br>
Mom: Ask your father.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I would personally call that being [evasive](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/evasive).

Answer (score 53):

When you do this you're *[dodging the question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_dodging)*.

> This may happen when the responder either doesn't know the answer and wants to avoid embarrassment, or when the responder is being interrogated or questioned in debate, and wants **to avoid giving a direct response.**

Similarly, from a comment, this is sometimes called "ducking the question" (h/t Scott).

Dodging the question is a form of [*deflection*](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/deflect):

> Etymology: 17th Century: from Latin dēflectere, from flectere to bend.

Comment: Or _ducking the question_.

Comment: Just beefed up your (best) answer with a reference per the bounty suggestion.

Comment: Bill, thanks for the contribution.  I hope you don't mind that I've edited your edit.

Answer (score 15):

You can also try:

- Circumlocution
- Circumbendibus
- Periphrasis

Comment: I'd like to see someone's face after you say to them "that's not an answer; that's circumbendibus" :)

Comment: Improvement: "That's not an answer--that, sir, is circumbendibusical!"

Comment: @DavidRivers You might want to throw in a "Indeed" or "Forsooth" somewhere for the added effect.

Comment: _Circumbendibus_ rather sounds like a Harry Potter spell!

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar "Circumbendibus!" The Circumlocution Charm - Effect: Dodges an uncomfortable question.

Answer (score 15):

For me, *fob* is a good word here, as in:

> I fobbed her off with a circumbendibus.

Comment: Pretty archaic to use fob as a verb though.

Comment: @mattacular [Fob off](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fob_off) is not archaic at all.

Comment: I think this is far more appropriate than the two top-rated answers so far. Being *evasive*, or *dodging the question* both tend to imply *failing to give an answer at all*. But if you *fob someone off*, you definitely give them *something* - in OP's case, definitely some kind of "answer", even if it's not the full/true/proper one.

Comment: In the United States it definitely is... Can't speak on UK

Comment: *fob off* is in common usage in British English.

Comment: It's common usage in Canada as well.

Answer (score 4):

**tergiversate**

> to be deliberately ambiguous or unclear in order to mislead or withhold information

<sup>[Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/tergiversate)</sup>

Comment: Interesting word, but a rare one.

Comment: @J.R.: True, though it _was_ Dictionary.com's 2011 [Word of the Year](http://hotword.dictionary.com/tergiversate/).

Comment: Usually tergiversate is employed when someone wants to delay the answer. The question here is related to situations in which one wants to avoid the answer. Subtle difference.

Answer (score 4):

Despite all the great synonyms for "lying", my word of choice is ***"sidestep"***.  Whether it be a parent who does not really know why the sky is blue but needs to save face with their child, or a politician who does not want to get caught answering a question with a horde of reporters recording their every utterance for posterity, the way out of the jam is to ***"sidestep"*** with an answer that is somewhere between vague and flat-out lying.

> ***"sidestep"***
>
> **transitive verb**
>
> 1: bypass, evade *sidestep a question*
>
> 2: to move out of the way of : avoid *sidestep a blow>*
>
> **intransitive verb**
>
> 1: to take a side step
>
> 2: to avoid an issue or decision
>
> **Examples of SIDESTEP**
>
> *"She sidestepped the reporter's question. They're sidestepping the real issue."
>
> First Known Use of SIDESTEP: 1900
>
> Related to SIDESTEP: Synonyms: beat, bypass, dodge, get around, shortcut, circumvent, skirt

definition and examples from Merriam-Webster Online

Answer (score 3):

The best answers above seem to be **evade** and **equivocate**, because both are general enough not to imply being deceitful or trickorius.

> ***evade*** 
>  verb \i-ˈvād, ē-\
>   evad·ed evad·ing
>   *intransitive verb*
>   1
>   : to slip away
>   2
>   : to take refuge in escape or avoidance
>   
>  *transitive verb*
>   1
>   : to elude by dexterity or stratagem
>   
>  2
>   a : to avoid facing up to 
>   b : to avoid the performance of : dodge, circumvent; especially : to fail to pay (taxes)
>   c : ***to avoid answering directly*** : turn aside
>   
>  3
>   : to be elusive to : baffle 
>   
>   
>   ***equiv·o·cate*** 
>  intransitive verb \i-ˈkwi-və-ˌkāt\
>   equiv·o·cat·ed equiv·o·cat·ing 
>  
>   1
>   : to use equivocal language especially with intent to deceive
>   
>  2
>   : ***to avoid committing oneself in what one says***
>   
>   
>   ***equivocal*** 
>   adjective \i-ˈkwi-və-kəl\ 
>  
>   1
>   a : ***subject to two or more interpretations*** and usually used to mislead or confuse 
>   b : uncertain as an indication or sign 
>   
>  2
>   a : of uncertain nature or classification 
>   b : of uncertain disposition toward a person or thing : undecided 
>   c : of doubtful advantage, genuineness, or moral rectitude

(Less formal, but perhaps more precise could be *dodge*, which is often used in the very example of a question being asked.)

Answer (score 2):

Consider *prevaricate*

> to speak falsely or misleadingly; deliberately misstate or create an incorrect impression; lie.

or *equivocate*

> to use ambiguous or unclear expressions, usually to avoid commitment or in order to mislead; prevaricate or hedge

Note, though, that both are usually used in contexts when the speakers wishes to actively mislead or avoid committing to an answer, rather than just avoiding the need to answer altogether.

Comment: Prevaricate is the correct word, in my opinion.
def: to deviate from the truth

Answer (score 2):

Two adjectives come to mind: "glib" and "pat".

"Glib" seems to me to imply a swift and deliberately evasive answer, one that may be even somewhat witty.

"Pat" implies to me that the answer is short, requires no thought to make, and  almost could be predicted.

Your first example is more glib than pat, for most people. The second example is pat.

Answer (score 1):

Neither "dodgy" nor "evasive" can capture instances where the generic answer is offered in jest. When humor is intended, an anti-joke is being cracked. Examples of [anti-jokes](http://anti-joke.com/):

> What's worse than finding a worm in your apple? The Holocaust
>
> Why did the boy drop his ice cream? Because he was hit by a bus.
>
> Why is the sky blue? Because God made it that way.

Answer (score 1):

In the world of NLP these types of answers are usually referred to as *distortions*.

This definition of *distorted* is based on world renowned linguist Noam Chomsky’s *[Transformational Generative Grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformational_generative_grammar)*.

The examples given are surface structures of distortion called *complex equivalence*, as referenced in *[Educational Psychology Casework:
A Practice Guide](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=QzexYqr0mnYC)* by Rick Beaver.

So for me these answers are *distorted*.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by fiat.

To directly respond to the Original Post: you want to avoid questions **that can only be answered by fiat**.

This wording is supported by several examples of "*(noun)* by fiat" or "*(verb)* by fiat", meaning justified by authority or arbitrary order, as opposed to logic or morality.

> You get an all-powerful magical creator with attributes that defy basic **logic by fiat**. We get... a rock.  -[Aspie, whywontgodhealamputees.com](http://whywontgodhealamputees.com/forums/index.php/topic,12805.90/wap2.html?PHPSESSID=48b3b27965538a565b7638eb01356c34)
>
> Obama’s bombshell **amnesty-by-fiat** is a subversion of straightforward immigration law. -[Charles Krauthammer, Washington Post](http://articles.washingtonpost.com/2012-06-21/opinions/35459364_1_immigration-laws-young-illegal-immigrants-congress-and-change)
>
> Applying a different rule may result in a different result, but both rules are **right by fiat**, because they define what they purport to represent. - [G. Scott Acton, University of California, San Francisco](http://www.personalityresearch.org/psychometrics/measurement.html)
>
> Measurements can be either (a) made when confirmed empirical theories may be used to support their existence; or (b) **made by fiat**, based on arbitrary definition. -[Ahmed Riahi Belkaoui, Accounting Theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=fE9STcvKw-QC&pg=PA44&dq=%22by%20fiat%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HkkNUe2DE-u00AH65YEQ&ved=0CFsQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22by%20fiat%22&f=false)

While the original post is looking for *one word*, and @Village's bounty also looks for *the word*, brevity has its limits.  No single word provided here captures that this answering strategy has a brutish quality lacking in reason or moral force.  Any discussion of avoidance should use a multi-word phrase that includes "**by fiat**".

And in final support of this phrasing, I offer that it is the best damn answer here because I say so.

Comment: Plus one for the real answer, *because-I-said-so*.

Answer (score 1):

Jon Purdy's suggestion of [non-answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49795/whats-a-word-for-avoiding-a-question-with-a-generic-fake-answer#comment92437_49795) is one I'd support.

Currently, only [Urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=non-answer) has a definition of it, but it is to an answer what a [non-apology apology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-apology_apology) is to an apology - you're pretending to answer (or apologize) but you aren't really doing so.

Answer (score 1):

I would call them "economic answers"—as they save the responder time.

Answer (score 0):

These might fall under [ignoratio elenchi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignoratio_elenchi) or [red herring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).

Comment: "Communism was just a red herring."

[Clue](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088930/quotes?ref_=tt_trv_qu)

Answer (score 0):

I would use *indirect* or *evade*.

Comment: This answer needs an explanation of why it is correct, including reference citations if applicable.

Comment: An indirect question is a completely different construct.  Do you mean _misdirection_?

Answer (score 0):

Colloquially, someone who does that could be **shining you on**. As slang, there aren't many authoritative sources, but it's very common, as evidenced in this discussion thread from [The Straight Dope](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=427790).

> *Quote: Originally Posted by NinetyWt*
>
> > *It is very common here in central Mississipppi. And, not just
> >     'agreeing with someone when you don't agree with them' but also
> >     encouraging someone to believe in something which isn't true, or
> >     valid, or likely to come to pass. As in "he kept sayin' he was gonna
> >     ask me to prom, but he was just shinin' me on" or "he kept hollerin'
> >     like he wanted to buy my truck but he was just shinin' me on".*
>
> What NinetyWt said. It was in use in norcal in the 1970's. Dunno about now.
>
> Shining me on is a good form of bullshit. As in, he was bullshitting
>   me.

Answer (score 0):

I've generally referred to this behavior as [cagey](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cagey), especially when it's clear that someone is unwilling to commit to an answer.