# Responding with a basic fact to imply a point of view is clearly flawed or wrong

Tags: single-word-requests, rhetoric, logic, argument-structure

What is a word or concept that describes a situation where one person puts forth a point of view, and another person does not directly address the position, but instead responds with an obvious, basic fact whose implications cast doubt on the correctness or strength of the point of view? This is intended to belittle the point of view.

Comment: Simply a counterargument.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Your response is actually an example of what I'm trying to describe, only applied to a question instead of a point of view. From my question, it is obvious that I'm describing a counterargument. However, my description contains several qualifiers which make the concept more specific than a generic counterargument. By responding with, "simply a counterargument," you're not accounting for those qualifications. Your response frustrates me because I have to take the time to re-explain something that is obvious from the original statement. This is a key feature of the concept.

Comment: Some of these answers might help you with this question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49795/whats-a-word-for-avoiding-a-question-with-a-generic-fake-answer/103107#103107

Comment: Surely the whole point of reasoned debate is (where necessary) the pointing out of facts that contradict the hypothesis? It's childish just to utter some paraphrase of 'You're wrong.' A counterargument could well be defined as 'a response stating a fact whose implications cast doubt on the correctness or strength of the point of view of the original proponent'. A _refutation_ would be a stronger term. I fail to see any obvious qualifications in your question that would make a hyponym more suitable. And in any case, I'm not sure there is such a word.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you're asking about an exchange like, "The moon is made from green cheese." -- "But Apollo 11 brought back samples of moon rock," then you're simply asking about a correction, or maybe a counter-assertion. Perhaps that's the word you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

[*Counterexample*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexample#In_philosophy): "used to argue that a certain [...] position is wrong by showing that it does not apply in certain cases".

Answer (score 0):

There are some slang terms I can think of: zinger, for instance. "She hit him with a zinger."
Not for very formal writing, of course. Another would be "put down," again, not formal at all. But both imply that the other speaker is right and the original speaker is wrong. "Comeback" is a third, but doesn't imply the correctness of the second speaker necessarily.