# What do you call a response which does not address the question?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, terminology

When some one is asked a question, sometimes if they are trying to avoid answering the question, they respond with something unrelated. What is the word for that response?

Eg. A: Why were you late?
    B: This bagel tastes good.

What I am looking for is the name of that response, not the action.

Comment: What I am looking for is the name of that response, not the action.

Comment: I am so disappointed that nobody has written a totally unrelated answer to this question.

Comment: @Oldcat Well, Oldcat, Rome wasn't built in a day.

Comment: @Centaurus Irrelevant, your honor!

Comment: On other Q&A sites they call it an "answer".

Comment: Actually, that could be "begging the question", in its poorly-understood original meaning.

Comment: Any kind of '[fallacy of irrelevance](http://www.philosophypages.com/lg/e06a.htm)' (many online examples) will suffice here, such as 'I was late because I have a doomed life' (appeal to pity) . But it seems you are looking for something totally off-topic 'I was late because ... hey look at that squirrel'. Is that right? Otherwise, other terms like avoidance or equivocation describe the response.

Comment: Too bad there isn't a word for "a politician's response", because that's exactly what this is.

Comment: I believe this is called "staying on message" in the political lexicon..

Comment: Another synonym for "a politician's response" could be "lie"

Comment: I may be crazy, but I think "response" may actually be what you're looking for. In your question, you've used it as a synonym for "answer", but it's not. A "response" is merely the reaction given to a stimulus, it does not describe the qualities within that reaction. You can respond without answering, but you can't answer without responding.  Depending on the situation, it would make sense to say "I got a response, but they didn't answer any of my questions."

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The response in that example could be called a [non sequitur](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/non+sequitur): 'a statement having little or no relevance to what preceded it'. This doesn't imply deliberate avoidance, however.

Comment: Despite OP's acceptance, I don't think this is an answer to the question. Rather it's an example of what OP was talking about. :-)

Comment: It'd only be a non sequitur if the person who responded had no intentions of avoiding the question. Depending on the context, it could be any of the several answers provided here but I think this is probably the least likely one given the context provided in the question.

Comment: @R, that's hilarious R.

Comment: A non sequitur is an unintentional evasion! The correct answer evaded ME!

Comment: But the `non sequitur` assumes that there is a logical statement where a conclusion does not follow from the premise. A question, as in the OP, is not a logical statement of this form. This answer is somewhat ... *irrelevant*.

Answer (score 54):

[*Evasion*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/evasion) is a common word used to describe that activity. Other words are hedging, diversion...

> an indirect answer; a prevaricating excuse; a trickery, cunning, or deception used to dodge a question, duty, etc; means of evading

Comment: Thanks for the upgrade, @medica. I like the red word links and the tan box links, but I haven't found out how to create them :>)

Comment: Scot, ">" (without quotes) will give you a box of text, and "[what you want here](webaddress)" gives you a hyperlink. Forgive my lack of familiarity with terms. I'm very challenged!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as the question is written.

Comment: @ScotM To see the formatting more clearly, simply click the “Edit” link on your answer; then you’ll see exactly what the code looks like. In addition, there is a small icon on the right-hand side of the formatting bar above the text (when editing), a yellow circle with a white question mark in it. Clicking on that icon will reveal a secondary help bar, which also has a link to “Advanced help”, where all the markdown you can use when writing answers is explained quite thoroughly.

Answer (score 21):

The term for this is a *non-answer*. The practice of giving non-answers could be described as *evasion*, *avoidance*, *dodging the question*, etc. A *non sequitur* is a statement that doesn't follow logically from the statements/premises that came before it, but in my experience it's not used to describe non-answers.

Answer (score 20):

To *[dodge a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49795/whats-a-word-for-avoiding-a-question-with-a-generic-fake-answer)* is a useful expression:

> - To evade (an obligation, for example) by cunning, trickery, or deceit: kept dodging the reporter’s questions.

(from [AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=dodge))

Comment: I wouldn't say OP's example shows much cunning.

Answer (score 13):

In the legal world, such an answer would be called ***non-responsive*** and is a well-known type of objection that can be raised against a witness' testimony.

http://thelawdictionary.org/nonresponsive-answer/

Answer (score 12):

*Non sequitur*

Merriam-Webster [says](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/non%20sequitur)

> a statement that is not connected in a logical or clear way to anything said before it

Comment: @Ellie Yes; that answer and mine were being typed at the same time, with it being posted a moment faster. I immediately gave credit in a comment on that answer. Mods have now removed such trivia. Such "cleanup" is not always helpful :-)

Comment: But I can't see that anyone will be helped by having the answer 'non-sequitur' here twice. Are rep points so important?

Comment: A perfect non sequitur. Two, in fact. If you check my activity you'll see I haven't posted to Stack Exchange in donkeys, and thus your question might be answered. The first statement is your personal business and I try not to discuss such problems in public.

Comment: Why not just delete the bloat then?

Comment: Ok @EdwinAshworth. Deleting now. Everything.

Answer (score 12):

The phrase [*changing the subject*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/change+the+subject) would fit.

> Deliberately talk about another topic, as in If someone asks you an embarrassing question, just change the subject. This term uses subject in the sense of “a topic of conversation,” a usage dating from the late 1500s.

Comment: "Non sequitor", the chosen answer of the OP, is a phrase and so technically does NOT answer the OP question: What is the WORD for that response? But who cares? It captures the essential thought. "Changing the subject" is also a phrase that captures the essence of the response.

Comment: @ScotM It could (and should, if you ask me) easily be argued that _non sequitur_ is a word, not a phrase. In fact, I find it rather more difficult to think of any cogent arguments for why it should be a phrase. Phrases are, after all, **linguistic** units in general, rather than orthographic units, so if we’re debating words vs. phrases, we must use the linguistic, rather than the orthographic, definition (to the extent that there is one) of _word_ as well—and the only way I can make _non sequitur_ not fit the bill of a word is by using the purely orthographic definition.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet. It would be an interesting argument. I agree that it is generally used as a word as if it were spelled "nonsequitur", but it is spelled "non sequitur", and in the Latin it is a two-word phrase translated (loosely) "not following". Since it is two words in the original language, and we spell the unit as two words in English, it seems legitimate to refer to it as a phrase, but it is a distinction I would never loose sleep over:)

Comment: @ScotM That's exactly what I meant by orthographic vs. linguistic definitions. Orthographically, “sta irs” is two words, while “hecamedownthestairs” is one, but that doesn't make a difference to the fact that linguistically, we're talking one and five words, respectively, with typos. In Latin, _non sequitur_ (‘it does not follow’) is certainly two words, but that's not really relevant for English. In Arabic, _algebra_ is two words, but not in English. A lexeme cannot be broken up, and _non sequitur_ fits that; a phrase can be broken up, and _non sequitur_ can't.

Comment: I'm smiling. You have correctly "refuted" the second leg of my argument, but we must still wrestle with the fact that non sequitur, unlike "algebra", is spelled as two separate words in English. I would not be opposed to overthrowing convention to make it "non-sequitur" or even "nonsequitur". I sleep soundly while our culture wrestles with the inconsistencies of our language.

Comment: @ScotM, I’m smiling, too, but that’s probably a result of sleep deprivation. How can you be so cavalier? In my humble opinion, neither “sta irs” nor “hecamedownthestairs” are words, orthographically or linguistically; while algebra was originally two Arabic words _algebra_: < ML < Ar al-jabr lit., restoration [link](http://www.definitions.net) the two word Latin phrase non sequiter remains two words, orthographically and linguistically, in English. Non sequiter carries no suggestion of the evasion.

Comment: Apparently our conversation is skewed @Little Eva. I offered two legitimate reasons to call "non sequitur" a phrase, acknowledging that I had no objection with calling it a word. Janus correctly "refuted" the one reason, but left the second reason un-answered. His jibberish examples did not refute my first reason, and they had no bearing on my second reason, so I ignored them as non sequitur in the discussion:) As you stated, my second reason for calling non sequitur a phrase stands un-refuted, but could be addressed by changing its spelling to non-sequitur or nonsequitur.

Comment: @ScotM, nothing skewed at all Scot, as I mentioned I was, and still am, smiling. I love the whole discussion and I was just practicing thinking and writing so I can keep up. I thought Janus' comments, as well as your own, were cogent. Non sequiter, though accepted by the OP, fails completely to address the heart of the question, which was concerned with evasion, no?

Comment: We're all clear then :) I feel @Jacques' opinion on the word choice should prevail. I am satisfied with his choice and the knowledge that many in the community felt my answer was good too. I voted several other options up, including non sequitur.

Comment: Upon further review, I find the argument offered by @JanusBahsJacquet to be superior, and concede that it is better to refer to non sequitur as a word.

Answer (score 11):

One option that's not been mentioned so far is ***deflection***, used as in sense three of Merriam-Webster's entry for [***deflect***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deflect): "to keep (something, such as a question) from affecting or being directed at a person or thing."

Answer (score 7):

You can say the person is *being evasive* or is giving *an evasive answer*:

> evasive - "tending or intended to evade"
>
> e.g. She gave an evasive answer  [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evasive)
>
> To be evasive is to avoid something, whether it's a touchy subject or the person who's "it".
>   If you're dodging the truth and not giving straight answers, then you're being evasive, which is probably not the best strategy when the police are asking the questions. From the French  évasif, it’s an adjective that describes someone who's being intentionally shifty or vague. But a concept that’s hard to pin down or comprehend can also be considered evasive.

Comment: This does not actually address the OP's question, who wanted to know what such a *response* is called. The correct answer is *non-sequitur*. Or, if you prefer, *an evasion*.

Comment: @medica To have "non-sequitur" as the answer, the question should have been better formulated.  "What rhetorical device...", "What kind of fallacy..."  The way it was phrased, I think "an evasive answer" is a perfect fit.

Comment: To each his (or her) own. I agree the wording could have been much better. But to blame the OP for a so-so answer is, well, i dunno. What's a good word for that (the actual false accusation, not the act of seeking to blame falsely)?

Comment: @medica: Calumny

Answer (score 6):

[red herring](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/red-herring)

> a fact, idea, or subject that takes people's attention away from the central point being considered:

Comment: Much like the answer giving *non sequitur*, this answer seems to be out of context. A *red herring* is specifically a fallacy used in making an argument. It's not a term for a non-answer in a general context.

Answer (score 4):

To provide a non sequitur to the question, to *stonewall*, according to Merriam-
Webster, is to,

> refuse or fail to answer questions, to do what has been requested, etc., especially in order to delay or prevent something

Answer (score 3):

That response is irrelevant.

ir·rel·e·vant

adjective

```
not connected with or relevant to something.
```

synonyms:   beside the point, immaterial, not pertinent, not germane, off the subject, unconnected, unrelated, peripheral, extraneous, inapposite, inapplicable; ...

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE! Please note that the source of quotations must be referenced explicitly in plain text as well as by a link. This is so that the source can still be identified if the link is not reproduced for some reason (for example, if SE content is reproduced badly elsewhere). [Link to relevant policy](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) You should also use the `>` format character to indicate the quoted material.

Answer (score 3):

*Inadequate* comes to mind. It's used when the answer doesn't meet the required standard, or is *irrelevant* (see @Jimbo's answer).

> "His reply was inadequate in answering my question"

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the answer is a *non sequitur* for cases where the response is truly unrelated, and that this tactic may be employed as a *dodge*, as in the example. But you can also answer with a seeming *non sequitur* as a way of *answering obliquely*.

This description would fit the example if B was late because he stopped to buy the bagel, and could express B's valuation of gustatory pleasure over punctuality.

---

There's a great example of this in the movie LA Confidential, when Kevin Spacey lies to a struggling boxer about getting his brother's prison term commuted. After the boxer has shared his information, fulfilling his part of the deal, he asks, "I'll hear from you about my brother?"

By way of reply, Spacey pantomimes a boxer's defensive stance and says: "Keep it up, Lenny. Up."

Comment: "Non sequitur" may be the best answer, but "oblique answer" is not bad!

Comment: @ScotM - actually I don't think any of the answers are bad. They're actually all good. They just don't fulfill the OP's request. Seeing as this was about fallacious responses, it kind of tickles me.

Answer (score 2):

When someone avoids answering the question posed and instead answers a subtly different but more favorable question, native speakers describe it with the euphemism *staying on message*. For example, consider the following excerpt from [Six Lines to Help you Stay on Message in a Media Interview](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/tim-ward/six-lines-to-help-you-sta_b_9381278.html) by Tim Ward.

> For scientists and other experts building their skills at staying on
> message, here are six tag lines we find helpful for staying on
> message:
>
> 1. “I hear your concern about X, and while that’s important, the heart of our research is really Y. Here’s why Y matters most...”
> 2. “You’ve raised an interesting point about X. Another interesting point that’s closer to our research is Y...”
> 3. “I’m not familiar with the details of the issue you raised, as it outside the scope of our research. What I can tell you about Y is...
> 4. “Well, we can agree to disagree about X. I would like to return to the topic of my research and share something about Y that we’ve not
>    yet touched on...”
> 5. “I can’t really speculate about X. Our research focuses on Y, and here’s what I can tell you...”
> 6. “While I am familiar with the issue of X, I’m here today to talk about the findings of our newest research on Y. Here’s what we think
>    is most important...”

This is a common tactic for politicians in debates and interviews.

Answer (score 1):

*Distraction* also fits the bill.

Answer (score 1):

Possible terms might be *tangential* or *circumstantial* speech.

[Tangential speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangential_speech) is a medical condition, possibly related to dementia, in which the sufferer doesn't reply directly to questions. However I have heard the term used in everyday speech to mean a response not directly related to the question.

> the train of thought of the speaker wanders and shows a lack of focus, never returning to the initial topic of the conversation.

Likewise, [circumstantial speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumstantial_speech) is also a psychiatric term, where the speaker may go off on a tangent but does eventually return to the primary topic.

> In circumstantiality, apparently unnecessary details and seemingly irrelevant remarks cause a delay in getting to the point.

This may be caused by a cognitive disorder (ASD, confusion) or it may be intentionally evasive.

Answer (score 1):

The question specifically states,

> What I am looking for is the name of that response, not the action.

An answer that does not address the question is unhelpful or not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Equivocate - "Use ambiguous language so as to conceal the truth or avoid committing oneself" OED online. You equivocate in order to avoid answering a question, to deflect the question, often by responding with a non sequitur.

Answer (score 0):

An

> intentional fallacy

could be appropriate if they want to deceive in a special kind of way.  A fallacy itself can be unintentional and does not really answer your question - where being

> intentionally fallacious

could be construed as avoiding the question. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy

I don't think it fits perfectly, as one could simply be obtuse (a little like your example) or ridiculous or evasive - which are not quite examples of fallacy arguments.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.thesaurus.com/e/synonym-of-the-day/circumvent-2023-10-23/

> CIRCUMVENT IS ANOTHER WORD FOR SKIRT
>
> Skirt means to go around the edge of something, avoid it, or keep your
> distance from it (I skirted the puddle because I didn’t want to get my
> shoes wet).
>
> Circumvent means to go around something or bypass it, often in a
> figurative way (The press release circumvented the real issues).
>
> Skirt and circumvent both mean to go around something, **and both can
> be used when someone doesn’t give a straight answer or when someone
> doesn’t want to discuss a certain issue** (I circumvented his
> question; I skirted the topic).
>
> Skirt primarily suggests staying away from a certain issue, whereas
> circumvent suggests finding a way to not have to discuss it.