# What is the term/expression for when someone responds with a complaint vs an answer to a question?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I’m trying to find the term or expression to describe the behaviour when someone responds to a simple question with a complaint vs the answer.

Eg

**Person A:)** (setting the table, trying to get the right count of place settings ) “Is Becky here for dinner tonight?”

**Person B:)** (hostile response) “I’ve told you 10 times, Becky is on night shifts on Wednesdays!”

Note it often requires the first person to re-ask the question as no clarity was provided in the response... which just causes more disgruntlement.

I’m guessing the term is close to “belittle” or “disparage” but I suspect there is a more accurate term.

Comment: It seems to me that Person B answered Person A's question: Becky is on night shift on Wednesdays. It's implicit that your exchange occurred on a Wednesday.

Comment: A term for something implies a noun. It is unclear what you are looking for as you give verbs “belittle/disparage” and you also give a noun phrase "hostile response", which is appropriate, but you seem to have rejected it.

Answer (score 1):

Others may find more suitable words but, to me, person B seems to be *captious* or *carping*, probably both. Most dictionaries will give you meanings similar to:

*captious* = an ill-natured inclination to stress faults and raise objections

*carping* =  marked by a querulous and perversely critical attitude.

Answer (score 0):

This is dismissive behaviour, though I doubt you'll find a term actually *denoting* both irritation / anger and a non-answer.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dismissive):

> **dismissive** [adjective]:
>
> serving to dismiss or reject someone or something : having or showing
> a disdainful attitude toward someone or something regarded as unworthy
> of serious attention
>
> - *He responded to the question with a dismissive wave.*

There is already a question addressing 'responding to a question with a reply that is not an answer': [What do you call a response which does not address the question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215722/what-do-you-call-a-response-which-does-not-address-the-question) (evasion, answering obliquely, answering with a non-sequitur, dodging the question etc).

Answer (score 0):

They're being *offhand* or *brusque*.

> **Offhand** (adj): Ungraciously or offensively nonchalant or cool in manner.
>
> Example: You were a bit offhand with her this afternoon.
>
>  [[Lexico]](https://www.lexico.com/definition/offhand)

> **Brusque:** Abrupt or offhand in speech or manner.
>
> Example: His brusque manner seemed to egg her on and she raised her chin a bit.
>
> [[Lexico]](https://www.lexico.com/definition/brusque)

I can't think of any word that connotes both *brusqueness* and *exasperation* at the same time. But you could us ethe following idioms:

- *They're brushing you off*
- *They're biting your head off*

> **Brush someone off:** If someone brushes you off when you speak to them, they refuse to talk to you or be nice to you.
>
> Example: When I tried to talk to her about it she just brushed me off.
>
>  [[Collins Dictionary]](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/brush-off)

> **Bite someone's head off:** to speak to someone angrily when there is no reason to.
>
> Example: I just asked if I could help – you don’t have to bite my head off!
>
>  [[CED]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bite-someone-s-head-off)