# Rhetoric word for answering a question with another answer implying the first

Tags: single-word-requests, figures-of-speech, rhetorical-devices

During a discussion on AI, it was asserted that AI is not yet handling very well cases where an indirect, but quite adequate (unless prevaricatory) answer is given.

Examples:

> **Person A:**  Are you going to do that history homework?
>   **Person B:**  I've just switched on my computer!
>
> **Person A:** Are we leaving soon?
>   **Person B:** I'm putting on my shoes as we speak.

Both questions are answered *yes*, but without being explicit. I know there is a single word describing this. I just don't remember it. The word is similar to *synecdoche* or **-onym*.

Comment: This question can definitely use some clarification/editing and formating, e.g. "Question: ... Answer:...", because the first two sentences certainly can be spoken by the same person, whereas the second pair are more a Q&A situation between two people. You're asking if there is a formal name for answering a question indirectly, is that right? If so, maybe "answering by implication".

Answer (score 1):

Based on a response to [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49795/whats-a-word-for-avoiding-a-question-with-a-generic-fake-answer) question, maybe the word you were thinking of was "circumlocution," "circumbendibus," or "periphrasis."

Personally, I'd just call it an indirect or implicit response.

Comment: Not the word I was looking for, the respondent is not doing it with intent of evading the question. But thanks anyway :)