# Suggestion for someone who talks a lot but says little

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, british-english

I know many politicians that avoid interview questions by talking a lot but not really communicating anything.

You could say that what they were saying was full of banalities or canned answers or that they were waffling, but is there a better word for this behaviour?

I'd like to say some thing like *That response was a _____* or *he\she is ___ing*?

Comment: What is the issue with "waffling"?

Comment: @Hank Mostly, it sounds a little informal but partly because there's a great deal of skill in talking for a long time without anyone noticing until afterwards that you actually haven't said anything at all.

Comment: What about "evasive"?

Comment: Related question (some answers that may be helpful): http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49795/whats-a-word-for-avoiding-a-question-with-a-generic-fake-answer

Comment: @KristinaLopez Related, aye.  They're both evasive.  I was looking for something more subtle.

Comment: Also related:[*What is a term or idiom for “blah blah blah” talk?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316399/what-is-a-term-or-idiom-for-blah-blah-blah-talk)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use *[**bloviate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bloviate)* and its various forms:

> a style of empty, pompous political speech particularly associated with Ohio due to the term's popularization by United States President Warren G. Harding, who, himself a master of the technique, described it as "the art of speaking for as long as the occasion warrants, and saying nothing". The verb "to bloviate" is the act of creating bloviation.
> <sub>*from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloviation)*</sub>
>
> to speak or write verbosely and windily
> <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bloviate)*</sub>

Thus, "that response was a bloviation" or "he/she is bloviating."

Comment: I like that, the word itself even sounds pompous and vacuous.

Comment: Bloviating seems to be a word that is becoming more well known. I'm seeing it used frequently in comments sections.  While it is certainly an insult in ways, I think it is a more direct criticism of "emptiness" of the speech, without accusing someone of essentially lying(as equivocate does), or being afraid to take a stand(as waffling does)

Answer (score 9):

The [google dictionary](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20windbag) defines *windbag* as :

> a person who talks at length but says little of value.

One can say "he/she is a windbag", though it is not clear that "he/she is windbagging" is proper usage.

Answer (score 0):

The word [vacuous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vacuous) just occurred to me.  (MW)

> emptied of or lacking content
>
> marked by lack of ideas or intelligence

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just looking for "dodging/avoiding the issue", or "beating around the bush".

As in "He or she is dodging the issue".

Slightly more than one word, hope it helps.

P.S. Maybe 'stonewalling'?

> Delay or obstruct (a request, process, or person) by refusing to answer questions or by being evasive.
>   "she has also stonewalled queries about her love life"

Answer (score -1):

I do not see a problem with waffling, but **equivocate** could work as a synonym.

> #### Equivocate
>
> *verb*
>
> - to use ambiguous or unclear expressions, usually to avoid commitment or in order to mislead; prevaricate or hedge.

([Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/equivocate))

Comment: This does not address the 'talks a lot' aspect (without which OP becomes a multi-duplicate).

Comment: It also has a very heavy flavor of "lying" as it has come to be used.  websters-merriams goes a step beyond the definition above:   "to use equivocal language especially with intent to deceive"  That is a pretty stiff accusation if understood that way.